# Snapping window to left/right half of the screen?

Tags: windows-8

In Windows 7 there was the one of my favorite features for wide screen monitor - ability to snap one application to left side of the window, and another to right by moving window title to left or right, now it snaps only to small part of the screen, so for example  to do comparison of two browser windows is not possible. Does Windows 8 still have ability to snap window to half of the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but only in Desktop. Snap in Desktop behaves more or less the same as in Windows 7.

You can't open two browser windows in Modern UI anyway.

Simply drag the window (within Desktop) to the side of Desktop (easier when it is full screen, thanks @JourneymanGeek), as you would do in Windows 7:

[[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWiFY.png)

It's also possible to use the side Snap for Modern UI (e.g. for chatting) at the same time as Desktop taking up the majority of the space with its own Snapping:

[[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S53zc.png)

Comment: it looks like only keyword support is left even in desktop mode, but that is better than nothing anyway :)

Comment: @Giedrius If you drag a window within Desktop to the side, it will snap as in Windows 7.

Comment: aerosnap works perfectly in the desktop the way it did in windows 7. The 'easy' way to do this is in a full screen desktop. You can then dock a metro app at the side.

Answer (score 3):

This is still possible for desktop apps (<kbd>[image: Windows]</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>[image: Windows]</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>), but not for Metro apps.

Answer (score 0):

No. Snapped apps have a fixed width of 320px and the divider has a fixed width of 22px so you can't snap an app to occupy half of the screen area.

[image]

But in the desktop mode, <kbd>Win</kbd> + 
<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> allows you to make a window occupy half of the screen area.